# Java/C++ Object creation order

Tags: java, c++, object

Please take a look at the following piece of code:

```
class Parent {
    Parent() {
        printFunction();
    }

    public void printFunction() {
        System.out.println("Parent Print");
    }

    class ParentInner {
       ParentInner() {
          InnerPrint();
       }

       void InnerPrint() {
          System.out.println("Parent Inner print");
       }
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    ChildInner ci;
    Child() {
        super();
        ci = new ChildInner();
    }

    @Override
    public void printFunction() {
        System.out.println("Child Print");
    }

    class ChildInner extends ParentInner {
       ChildInner() {
          super();
       }

       @Override
       void InnerPrint() {
          System.out.println("Child Inner print");
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
    }
}
```

The output of this code from a Java compiler (both eclipse and linux) is:

```
Child print
Child Inner print
```

This, in C++ (gcc)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

class Parent {
    public:
    Parent() {
        printFunction();
    }

    virtual void printFunction() {
        cout << "Parent print\n";
    }

    class ParentInner {
       public:
       ParentInner() {
          InnerPrint();
       }

       virtual void InnerPrint() {
          cout << "Parent Inner print\n";
       }
    };
};

class Child : public Parent {
    public:
    Child():Parent() {
        ci = new ChildInner();
    }

    void printFunction() {
        cout << "Child print\n";
    }

    class ChildInner : public ParentInner {
       public:
       ChildInner():ParentInner() {
       }

       void InnerPrint() {
          cout << "Child Inner print\n";
       }
    };

    ChildInner *ci;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   Child *c = new Child();
   return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
Parent print
Parent Inner print
```

What say? I think the base class gets created first, then the child- gcc is logical. What's up in Java?

Comment: What's your C++ code?

Comment: It's impossible to say anything without seeing the C++ code.

Comment: The Java part is easy to understand: Child is overriding all Parent methods, so all Parent behavior is removed

Comment: Same is the case in C++. Why should the order differ there then?

Answer (score 0):

It's as you suspect. When you call the `Parent` constructor from the `Child` constructors initializer list, the `Child` object is not fully created yet. So in a way there is no `Child` object yet, just the `Parent` object.

Comment: That's what I thought- it makes sense in C++. In Java, it prints the other way round - all child prints.

Comment: @GreenBee While C++ and Java have many similarities, they are mostly syntactical. C++ and Java are still very different languages, and among those differences are things like member function overriding and binding.

Comment: True, I deduced that too :) Are there any resources for understanding the object creation in the two? This looks baffling. I could not find a resource that explains the above flow properly - mainly the difference.